# closure of an attribute A with multiple B attributes

Tags: database, closures, relation, functional-dependencies

Let's say we have a relation R(cinemaroomNumber,properties) that has 2 attributes cinemaroomNumber and (technical cinemaroom) properties . As an example, i'll give 3 tuples (4, 3D) , (4, Dolby) , (3, Dolby).

Can i say that there is a functional dependency cinemaroomNumber->properties so that the closure of cinemaroomNumber is {cinemaroomNumber}+ = {cinemaroomNumber,properties}?

I doubt this because a cinemaroom can have multiple properties.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A functional dependency claims, "Given one value for X, I can determine one and only one value for Y." In your case, given the cinema room number '4', you find two different values: '3D' and 'Dolby'.

So, no, `cinemaroomNumber->properties` is not a functional dependency in R.

The closure of cinemaroomNumber in R seems to be just cinemaroomNumber.